# Indicator of utility of Q/A to OP

Tags: discussion

I get the impression, perhaps falsely, that some/many users will post a question, then never return.

Is there a widget available that would indicate how 'involved' an OP is in their history of questions, and in the current question?

Answer (score 3):

I find an individual's reputation to be a quick indicator. If the only rep they have is from the question they just asked, and they aren't responding to any comments, then there's a much higher chance they aren't planning to return.

Comment: I look at it that way too.  Perhaps there could be a mechanism to decrement points if the OP does not reply to a direct question.  Sometimes I put a lot into a answer and over the ensuing days get the feeling it's wasted.  So I'm moving towards brief answers.  If they need more info, it's up to them to ask.

Comment: @mike Realize that your answer may also be helping others, not just the OP. I tend to keep answers a little generic for that reason.

Comment: true, but others can ask for more details too, not just the OP. I'll keep your idea of generality in mind in the future, thanks.